# how to check if any of the value is already hidden in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have two button in iPhone app I want that if button1 is hidden and when we create PDF then we may check that button1 is already hidden then does not hide it again and also does not show it back when PDF generated because when PDF is created I hide some buttons.

Comment: Use a `BOOL` instance variable that holds the condition you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write something like below...

```
if(button1.hidden){

//here button1 is hidden , so you can write code accordingly...
}else{
//here button1 is  not hidden , so you can write code accordingly...
}
```

happy coding!!!!!

Comment: Doesn't this break the MVC pattern?  You are using the [V]iew to hold state, which belongs in the [M]odel.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the .hidden property on the button

To hide the button, if not already hidden

```
if(!yourButton.hidden) //Button is not hidden 
{
   //hide button
   yourButton.hidden = YES;

   //do other magic here if required 
}
```

To change the visibility of your button, you can use

```
yourButton.hidden = YES;  //Set button hidden, (YES or NO, NO is by default)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check that `UIButton` is Hidden or not with its `isHidden` Property and also Hide that `UIButton` with its `setHidden:` method.

use this bellow logic with its method

```
if ([button1 isHidden]) {
     //Generate your PDF here because if Button is hide then this condition true and load this code
}
else{
     [button1 setHidden:YES];//we hide that button here and after load your code here
}
```